# Updating results when an opinion poll is answered

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I am trying to build an opinion poll app, such that I can create a template of an opinion poll, give it multiple sections/questions, assign multiple people to different copies of a given question, create varying measures (happiness, successfulness, greenness) and assign different questions different weights to apply to all of these measures.

My schema could then be something like:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE opinion_poll_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE opinion_poll_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE section_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE section_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_instances(id),
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES section_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE question_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  section_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES section_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE measure_templates (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_templates(id)
);

CREATE TABLE answer_options (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  question_template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES question_templates(id),
  weight FLOAT8
);

CREATE TABLE question_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES question_templates(id),
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_instances(id),
  section_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES section_instances(id),
  answer_option_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES answer_options(id),
  contributor_id INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE measure_instances (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  opinion_poll_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES opinion_poll_instances(id),
  template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES measure_templates(id),
  total_score FLOAT8
);

CREATE TABLE scores (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  question_template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES question_templates(id),
  measure_template_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES measure_templates(id),
  score INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO opinion_poll_templates(id) VALUES(1);

INSERT INTO opinion_poll_instances(id, template_id) VALUES (1,1);

INSERT INTO opinion_poll_instances(id, template_id) VALUES (2, 1);

INSERT INTO section_templates(id, opinion_poll_id) VALUES (1,1);

INSERT INTO section_instances(id, opinion_poll_id, template_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO section_instances(id, opinion_poll_id, template_id) VALUES (2, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO question_templates(id, section_id) VALUES (1, 1);

INSERT INTO question_templates(id, section_id) VALUES (2, 1);

INSERT INTO answer_options(id, question_template_id, weight) VALUES (1, 1, 0.5);

INSERT INTO answer_options(id, question_template_id, weight) VALUES (2, 1, 0.25);

INSERT INTO answer_options(id, question_template_id, weight) VALUES (3, 2, 0.75);

INSERT INTO measure_templates(id, opinion_poll_id) VALUES (1, 1);

INSERT INTO measure_templates(id, opinion_poll_id) VALUES (2, 1);

INSERT INTO question_instances(id, template_id, section_id, opinion_poll_id, answer_option_id, contributor_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO question_instances(id, template_id, section_id, opinion_poll_id, answer_option_id, contributor_id) VALUES (2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2);

INSERT INTO question_instances(id, template_id, section_id, opinion_poll_id, answer_option_id, contributor_id) VALUES (3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1);

INSERT INTO question_instances(id, template_id, section_id, opinion_poll_id, answer_option_id, contributor_id) VALUES (4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO question_instances(id, template_id, section_id, opinion_poll_id, answer_option_id, contributor_id) VALUES (5, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2);

INSERT INTO question_instances(id, template_id, section_id, opinion_poll_id, answer_option_id, contributor_id) VALUES (6, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1);


INSERT INTO measure_instances(id, opinion_poll_id, template_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1);

INSERT INTO measure_instances(id, opinion_poll_id, template_id) VALUES (2, 2, 1);

INSERT INTO scores(id, question_template_id, measure_template_id, score) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 100);

INSERT INTO scores(id, question_template_id, measure_template_id, score) VALUES (2, 2, 1, 1000);
```

and my query (living in a trigger on answer selection) could be something like:

```
WITH per_question_percentage AS (  
      SELECT SUM(answer_options.weight)/COUNT(question_instances.id) percentage, question_templates.id qid, opinion_poll_instances.id oid
      FROM question_instances
      INNER JOIN answer_options ON question_instances.answer_option_id = answer_options.id
      INNER JOIN question_templates ON question_templates.id = question_instances.template_id
      INNER JOIN opinion_poll_instances ON opinion_poll_instances.id = question_instances.opinion_poll_id
      GROUP BY question_templates.id, opinion_poll_instances.id
    ), max_per_measure AS (
      SELECT SUM(scores.score), measure_instances.id mid, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id oid
      FROM measure_instances
      INNER JOIN scores ON scores.measure_template_id=measure_instances.template_id
      GROUP BY measure_instances.id, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id
    ), per_measure_per_opinion_poll AS (
      SELECT per_question_percentage.percentage * scores.score score, measure_instances.id mid, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id oid
      FROM question_instances
      INNER JOIN scores ON question_instances.template_id = scores.question_template_id
      INNER JOIN measure_instances ON measure_instances.template_id = scores.measure_template_id
      INNER JOIN max_per_measure ON measure_instances.id = max_per_measure.mid
      INNER JOIN per_question_percentage ON per_question_percentage.qid = question_instances.template_id
      WHERE measure_instances.opinion_poll_id = question_instances.opinion_poll_id AND question_instances.opinion_poll_id = per_question_percentage.oid
      GROUP BY measure_instances.id, measure_instances.opinion_poll_id, per_question_percentage.percentage, scores.score
    ) 
    UPDATE measure_instances
    SET total_score = subquery.result*100
    FROM (SELECT SUM(per_measure_per_opinion_poll.score)/max_per_measure.sum result, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.mid, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.oid
          FROM  max_per_measure, per_measure_per_opinion_poll
          WHERE per_measure_per_opinion_poll.mid = max_per_measure.mid 
          AND per_measure_per_opinion_poll.oid = max_per_measure.oid
          GROUP BY max_per_measure.sum, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.mid, per_measure_per_opinion_poll.oid)
          AS subquery(result, mid, oid)
    WHERE measure_instances.id = subquery.mid
    AND measure_instances.opinion_poll_id = subquery.oid
    RETURNING total_score;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7604e/8

I am relatively inexperienced in SQL so I have multiple questions:

1. Is this best practices SQL? Is there a better/more canonical way to achieve this kind of result?
2. Is there a more effective way to do so? A more performant way?
3. I note that I end up joining across some of these tables (`measure_instances` for one) multiple times. Is there a way to share this kind of scope across CTEs?
4. Are CTEs even the right tool for the job?
5. Is there a better schema I should have used?

Comment: Your question seems a bit hypothetical, but I also think it has sufficient meat to it for it to be reviewable. I'm kind of hoping this isn't closed.